# NUnit Assert on a collection, checking for the existence of a value

Tags: collections, nunit, assert

I am writing an Assert in NUnit that checks for the existence of a value.

Is there a cleaner way of writing this statement?
Assert.That(quoteRequest.Errors.Count(x => x.Code == ErrorCodes.TitleIsEmpty), 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`CollectionAssert`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.5.10) class to do this:

```
CollectionAssert.Contains(IEnumerable expected, object actual);
```

So yours would look like:

```
CollectionAssert.Contains(quoteRequest.Errors, ErrorCodes.TitleIsEmpty);
```